# I want to get element which not contain certain text and click on its closest button

Tags: cypress, element

I want to get any element which not have "author-name user1" and click on button on that certain item block.

For example there are too many users and every user have a drawer menu I want to open drawer menu of anyone expect my own

```js
cy.get(".author-name").not().contains("User1").closest("button.btn").click()
```

```html
   <div class="item1">
        <div class="slideInRight animated">
        <div class="status">
        <div class="status-meta">
        <div class="author-name"> User1 </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <partie-drawer-menu>
        <buton class="btn"> This is Button</buton>
        <div class="menu-drawer">
        <div class="content">
        Menue Drawer Contents
        </div>
        </div>
        </partie-drawer-menu>
        </div> 

        <div class="item2">
        <div class="slideInRight animated">
        <div class="status">
        <div class="status-meta">
        <div class="author-name"> User2 </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <partie-drawer-menu>
        <buton class="btn"> This is Button</buton>
        <div class="menu-drawer">
        <div class="content">
        Menue Drawer Contents
        </div>
        </div>
        </partie-drawer-menu>
        </div> 

        <div class="item3">
        <div class="slideInRight animated">
        <div class="status">
        <div class="status-meta">
        <div class="author-name"> User3 </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <partie-drawer-menu>
        <buton class="btn"> This is Button</buton>
        <div class="menu-drawer">
        <div class="content">
        Menue Drawer Contents
        </div>
        </div>
        </partie-drawer-menu>
        </div>
```

I want to get any element which not have "author-name user1" and click on button on that certain item block.

For example there are too many users and every user have a drawer menu I want to open drawer menu of anyone expect my own

Answer (score 0):

I am able to found certain element and able to click on it but not able to stop for each loop. return false is not working

any solution please

```js
    cy.get("div.author-name").each(($el, index, $list) => {
      var $name = $el.text();
       if ($name !== " User1") {
        cy.log(index);
        cy.get($el).closest("partie-feed-item").find("button.btn> img").click();
        return false
            
      }
```

I am able to found certain element and able to click on it but not able to stop for each loop. return false is not working

any solution please[See Image Please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x97m.png)